# AWS Python: Migrate data from a table in S3 to another

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

Migrate data from a table in S3 (A) to another table I'm creating (B),
The difference between A and B is going to be that B will have more fields and a change of datatype.

I was thinking on doing it by extracting A into a Pandas DF, modifying it to look like B and uploading it to B, but I also believe that it will be inefficient. So I would like to know if there is a way to do it in a more efficient way.

My column types are the following

```
A_COLUMN_TYPES_NORMALISED_FIELDS = {
    'uuid': 'integer',
    'source': 'string',
    'job_title': 'string',
    'salary': 'int',
    'seniority': 'string',
}

B_COLUMN_TYPES_NORMALISED_FIELDS = {
    'uuid': 'integer',
    'source': 'string',
    'job_title': 'string',
    'salary': 'string',
    'seniority': 'string',
    'extra_info': 'string',
    'field': 'string',
}
```

The way I'm storing the data is with awswrangler

```
import awswrangler as wr

wr.s3.to_parquet(
            df.loc[:, columns],
            path=f's3://{cfg.AWS_BUCKET_NAME}/{path}',
            dataset=True,
            database=database,
            table=table,
            partition_cols=partition_cols,
            compression='gzip',
            dtype=dtype
        )
```

Comment: Does this work? What's inefficient about it?

Comment: Doing it this way I'll have to download a TB of data to my PC and re-upload it. I would like to do it in the database or in a way I don't have to download the data

Comment: It sounds like the inefficient part is that you are running the code locally. If you spun up a temporary EC2 instance in the same region as the S3 bucket, and ran the code there, there would be no download/upload outside of the S3 region and it would go much faster.

Comment: Given that S3 does not support updating of object content (you can only replace objects), you don't have any options for in-place editing. So, you'll have to download/transform/upload. Mark's suggestion for doing this in-region is the way to go, possibly using EC2 or even EMR.

Comment: I suggest that you take a look at the new format of Iceberg: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-iceberg-evolving-table-schema.html